# what is the logic and the answer

Tags: puzzle

here is one question my friend sent me. What can be the last two numbers' answers and can you also tell the logic, thanks

4072=1
3489=3
6517=1
9682=4
7678=3
1020=2
9345=?
9807=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$9345 = 1$ and $9807 = 4$.  One counts the number of circles made by the numerals.  So a 0, 6 and 9 count as 1 and an 8 counts as 2.